# When are questions migrated to other Stack Exchange communities? Are the reputation points also migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

A few days back, I answered a question on Meta Stack Overflow, but today, I found that the question was migrated to Stack Overflow. I could not get an appropriate reason as to why the question was migrated.

Also, I wanted to know if I have upvotes on the question, are they also migrated to the other account?

Comment: Could you link to that question? Migrations from MSO to SO are very rare. As for rep, it migrates with the question.

Comment: I just want to know that if some one could migrate my question from this account to stack overflow..??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean at all. This question is not a question that belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am not talking about this question. I am not able to ask questions in stack overflow. So i was thinking that, if i ask question in this account and if someone migrates my question to stack overflow.!!

Comment: Do **NOT** do that. If you ask a technical question here it will get closed real fast, it will not get migrated, and it will acquire ~10 downvotes before getting deleted by a mod (typically). Questions are essentially never migrated from here, especially not when the OP is banned from asking on the target site. Read all that's written on the question pointed to by the link you get on the ban message. That's the only way to get your account reinstated on SO.

Comment: But i had been banned from the last month. I have gained good reputation between this time, editted my questions, yet not able to ask questions. I am in real urgency to ask technical questions.

Comment: Re-read my previous comment: read that linked question's answer. What is described there are **the only ways** to get your account to ask questions again.

Comment: which link you are talking about

Comment: If you have a question ban, there's a link on that ban page.

Comment: All posts points to,  improve your questions, gain reputation. I have tried all that, still the ban is not removed. what else can i do. or these are just theories to edit and blah blah. I dont think the ban is going to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question has been migrated to Stack Overflow, it means the question was about programming. Meta Stack Overflow is the site where users ask why questions have been migrated, closed, or deleted; report bugs found on Stack Exchange sites; propose features for Stack Exchange sites they think useful for other users; ask questions about how things work on a Stack Exchange site.

Migrations from Meta Stack Overflow to Stack Overflow are rare; they are generally done if the question is about Stack Exchange programming, and it is thought to be generic enough to be answerable on Stack Overflow. Otherwise, if you ask on Meta Stack Overflow a question that is for Stack Overflow, the question is simply closed, and deleted. Migrating a question to Stack Overflow is not the way to by-pass a question ban on Stack Overflow. First off, there isn't a migration path from a meta site to the main site; even if there would be such migration path, migrations are blocked, when a user has a question ban on the destination site.

When a question is migrated, also the reputation that has been gained with the post that is migrated is migrated. There is just an exception for questions with a negative score, for which the question score is reset when the question is migrated; this means the OP will not lose reputation when the question is migrated.

Comment: I just want to know that if some one could migrate my question from this account to stack overflow..??

Comment: If you asked here a question for Stack Overflow, it will be just closed, and not migrated.

Comment: then what can i do instead to ask technical questions.

Comment: Furthermore, your question is, "A few days back, I answered a question on Meta Stack Overflow, but **today, I found** that the question was migrated to Stack Overflow." It implies your question was migrated to SO, not that there is a question you want migrated.

Comment: There are other ways to remove a question ban; asking questions on Meta Stack Overflow to migrate them on Stack Overflow is not one of them..

Comment: It was not my question. I just answered someone else's post. But now i want to ask question in stack overflow, as i am banned from it. I need some altrenative trick to ask questions in SO.

Comment: Then what are those ways..!

Comment: There is already [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) about what you can do when you get a question/answer ban. I will not repeat it here, as this very question is about a question that is migrated from Meta Stack Overflow to Stack Overflow, to which I have already replied.

Comment: I have tried all that stuff. edited all my posts, gained good reputation. Now should pray to god and leave the job until i the ban is removed from me.